# Line chart not drawn to scale

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any way that this chart is not drawn to scale?

http://forum.highcharts.com/resources/image/4227

I need every point occupies a separate row and evenly.

That is, in this graph, it should appear one line for each of the first 2 points of each series and the vertical distance between each should be the same as the distance between the lines below.

The series are dynamically loaded and the number of points each serie is variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/fpanci/yL6mw/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#container").highcharts({
            chart: {
                inverted: true,
                spacingLeft: 0,
                spacingRight: 0
            },
            title: {
                text: ' ',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                minorGridLineColor: '#000000',
                minorGridLineWidth: 1,
                minorTickLength: 0,
                minorTickInterval: 1,
                tickInterval: 1,
                labels: { enabled: true },
                maxPadding: 0.05,
                min: 0
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: { text: ' ' },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#C0C0C0'
                }],
                labels: { enabled: true },
                minorGridLineWidth: 1,
                minorTickLength: 0,
                minorTickInterval: 20,
                tickInterval: 20,
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            },
            exporting: { enabled: false },
            tooltip: { enabled: false },
            legend: { enabled: false },
            series: [{
                color: '#0000FF',
                connectNulls: true,
                data: [[0.2, 24.25], [0.5, 30.61], [1, 43.61], [2, 34.51], [3, 32.39], [4, 36.47], [5, 36.4], [6, null], [7, 24.68], [8, 37.79]]
            },{
                color: '#980000',
                dashStyle: 'shortdot',
                connectNulls: true,
                data: [[0.2, 38], [0.5, 52], [1, 50], [2, null], [3, 32], [4, null], [5, 34], [6, null], [7, 25], [8, null]]
            },{
                color: '#38761D',
                dashStyle: 'ShortDashDotDot',
                connectNulls: true,
                data: [[0.2, 20], [0.5, 27], [1, 35], [2, null], [3, 29], [4, null], [5, 30], [6, null], [7, 22], [8, null]]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for - the data appears to be plotting exactly where you've told it to...  Can you be more specific, or provide an illustration of what is not right?

Comment: Could you attach your goal, how chart should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is plotting exactly where you've told it to.
Your first 2 x values in each data set are 0.2 and 0.5 - so that is where the points are plotted.

If you don't want them plotted that way, just remove the x values from the data, and they will plot in sequence.

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yL6mw/1/

If you want to have the 0.2 and 0.5 as axis labels, but want them evenly spaced still, you'll need to use categories for your x axis.

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yL6mw/2/

Comment: Thanks, the second example is what i've been looking for.:D